# ANDROID_HOME not applied

Tags: android, linux, bash, shell

I try to set `ANDROID_HOME`  in bash, I use `CentOs 7`.
First, try to `export` with

```
 export ANDROID_HOME=/home/zhilevan/Android/Sdk
```

Then

```
export PATH=${PATH}:$ANDROID_HOME/tools:$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools
```

and w hen I type `$ android` it added correctly.

**Problem is:** when I close  terminal and then type `android`  faced with `bash: android: command not found...`

In another effort, in last step I type `source .bashrc` but the result is the same "after closing the terminal android :command not found".

**where is the problem,why  it  not work?**

Comment: If you didn't edit the bashrc, then sourcing it doesn't do much

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It does not work because when you open a new terminal, the exports no longer exist in the new shell. You need to add them to the *~/.bashrc* file which is loaded when opening a new terminal.

Add these two exports in *~/.bashrc*:

```
export ANDROID_HOME=/home/zhilevan/Android/Sdk
export PATH=${PATH}:$ANDROID_HOME/tools:$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools
```

You can run the following command to add them from terminal:

```
echo '
export ANDROID_HOME=/home/zhilevan/Android/Sdk
export PATH=${PATH}:$ANDROID_HOME/tools:$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools
' >> ~/.bashrc
```

Then source the ~/.bashrc (or open a new terminal)

```
source ~/.bashrc
```

Comment: I try that  and when `cat ~/.bashrc`  I saw  `export ANDRIOID_HOME=/home/zhilevan/Android/Sdk
export PATH=${PATH}:$ANDROID_HOME/tools:$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools` in end of it.
but again when  type `android` => `andorid:command not found`

Comment: @zhilevan : I missed that there was a misspelling too. `ANDROID` is misspelled in first export

Comment: yes, it was mistyping :D . thanks it worked correctly